# Separate string into multiple variables with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript I want to take a string like this `var hashStr = 'modal-123456'` and assign the string left of the `-` to a variable and the string right of the `-` to another variable.

If the string does not contain a `-` then ignore it.

How can I best achieve this?

```
var hashStr = location.hash.replace('#', '');

// hashStr now === 'modal-123456'

var firstHalf = // modal

var secondHalf = // '123456'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use split API.

```
var hashStr = 'modal-123456'
var splitStr = hashStr.split('-');
console.log(splitStr[0])
console.log(splitStr[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```js
var hashStr = 'modal-123456';
var [firstHalf, secondHalf] = hashStr.split("-");

console.log("first half:", firstHalf);
console.log("second half:", secondHalf);
```

Comment: this will work only in destructuring support js engines.

Comment: Yes. However, destructuring is now supported by chrome, firefox, edge, safari and nodejs. It is not supported by IE though. But this is a detail of the solution. You can easily use array indexes if you need to support old browsers. You can also use [babel](http://babeljs.io) because it rocks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
var hashStr = location.hash.replace('#', '');
var firstHalf = hashStr.split("-")[0];
var secondHalf = hashStr.split("-")[1];
```

or

```
var hashStr = location.hash.replace('#', '').split("-");
var firstHalf = hashStr[0];
var secondHalf = hashStr[1];
```